# How to remove all items from QListWidgetItem?

Tags: qt, items, qlistwidgetitem

I have a `QListWidgetItem`  and I have a PushButton that when clicked has to remove all the items. I use this:

```
void Model::removeEverything() {
     Container<Avatar*>::iterator startValue = list->begin();
     Container<Avatar*>::iterator endValue = list->end();

    while(startValue != endValue) {
        remove(*startValue);
        ++startValue;
    }
}

void Modello::remove(Avatar* a) {
    list->removeElement(a);
}
```

But `removeEverything()` doesn't delete everything. It deletes all item except the second. And when I have only one item in the list and I try to use `removeEverything()` the program crashes.
I don't understand what I'm missing. I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: Your code can't even compile - on the one hand you access 'list', on the other 'lista' and you did not tell us what type this is.

Comment: It was just my mistake. They are both list

Comment: Then it's a plain c++ error - you're modifying the container but don't modify the end iterator afterwards.

Comment: So how can i solve the problem?

Comment: E.g by using a for loop starting from the end, or fixing your end after you modified the container.